# syntax checking/correcting on Geany 0.20

Tags: ide, editor, geany

Since few days, I am experimenting with lots of Editors/IDEs. I am looking for good IDE for Python on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine. After trying almost all the IDEs, I finally ended with Geany 0.20.

Everything is working as my requirements except syntax checking/correcting. I also used Eclipse and I really liked syntax errors checking in it. Is there any plugin to check/correct syntax errors on Geany?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, a plug-in like that does not exist. But, you can send your idea to their mailing list or develop it yourself then send it to them because I think many people would benefit from a plug-in like that(me being one of those people :).

Comment: This can be done using F8 (compile command), it shows red line and exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon Vinoth.3v's answer, I implemented it via the following build command (not for python, but the concept is the same)

- Build (menu bar)
- Set Build Commands
- Under 'Independent commands' beside 'Make' I set the command to "jshint %f"
- Now under Edit -> Preferences -> Keybindings -> toward the bottom I set "Make all" to ctrl+g

with the above settings, I can hit ctrl+g to run jshint on the current file and have the output show up in the Compiler tab of the Messages Window.  It's not quite red squiggly lines, but I never trusted those anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compile buton/menu to build it, so it displays the Syntax errors.

I am using php on Geany, Works Great.